# What would happen if the Higgs boson and the $Z$ boson collided?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, higgs

I am thinking the $z$ boson would remain with the combined mass of both the $Z$ boson and the Higgs boson. This is because the Higgs boson is a spin-0 boson and the $Z$ boson is a spin-1 boson.

Comment: ls also this https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/266741/feynman-diagram-elementary-vertex-with-4-lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Standard Model allows two possibilities: The $Z$ can absorb the Higgs, or they can scatter off each other. The first corresponds to a three-particle $HZZ$ vertex in a Feynman diagram and the second to a four-particle $HHZZ$ vertex. You can see these two possible vertices in the answer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/313083/interaction-terms-in-the-standard-model-which-cause-higgs-decay-to-electroweak-b).

Answer (score 2):

You seem to believe particles absorb/trade masses in reactions. They only trade energy and momentum.

For a real *Z* absorbing a real *h* to end up with a real *Z*, you'd need both energy and momentum to balance across the reaction. In the center-of momentum frame of the input particles *Z* and *H* you'd then have a total energy 
$$
E=\sqrt{m_Z^2 + p^2} + \sqrt{m_h^2 + p^2},
$$
and zero total momentum, by frame choice. The output *Z* would then be at rest, with total energy $E=m_Z$.

However, for absolutely any *p*, including 0,
$$
m_Z\neq \sqrt{m_Z^2 + p^2} + \sqrt{m_h^2 + p^2},
$$
so your reaction will not go.

Comment: The masses count as energy. I mean energy in the masses get absorbed.

Comment: What about 2 z bosons

Comment: There is no *HZZZ* vertex in the SM, and I believe there is no tree diagram you can cook up for this, as per [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/525025/what-are-all-the-possible-direct-interactions-between-bosons-in-standard-model).

Comment: @Roghan Appreciative of the key point?